# Popup Box with Link to other google Document in Google Document

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have a script that I run from the menu of a google document. It essentially functions like this one: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/47173/how-to-automatically-open-a-created-text-document-after-it-being-created/47649#47649.

I want a function that is similar the one in the link above except that the popup with the link is shown in a google doc rather than a google spreadsheet. That part of my script looks like this (title and url are defined above that part):

```
var docnew = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();

var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle("Open Doc")
.setHeight(50).setWidth(400);
var vPanel = app.createVerticalPanel().add(app.createAnchor(title, url));

app.add(vPanel);
docnew.show(app);
```

I then get the following error. "TypeError: Funktion show in Objekt Document nicht gefunden", which is German and means  "TypeError: Function show not found in object Document".

Can somebody help me with this?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Best,

Phil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The show method works only in spreadsheets, in Google Documents (and also in the new version of spreadsheets) you can use this code :

```
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(argument);
```

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs) shows some examples.

Your code snippet would be like this :

```
function showUi(){
  var docnew = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var app = UiApp.createApplication()
  .setHeight(50).setWidth(400);
  var vPanel = app.createVerticalPanel().add(app.createAnchor(title, url));
  app.add(vPanel);
  DocumentApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(app,"Open Doc");
}
```